# VLC Media Player synchronization over network

Tags: sync, vlc-media-player, playback

I need to sync 4 players over a network. These are 4 pieces of content which are combined to create a 360 degree immersive experience. Each Windows PC is a mosaic feeding multiple projectors. I simply need VNC to run in full screen with the various resolutions and receive a control command from Crestron (UDP or whatever)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Hello, no idea what you're specifically writing about. Are you perhaps talking about something like NDI technology, which would allow you to stream from several devices? Instead of assigning random tags like "NVidia graphics card", focus on quality of the question, please.